# How to detect the executed suitescript filenames in NetSuite record?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

As you may know, once there is a new suite script version, we need to update the appointed script file in its script development.

But sometimes we may not know if the new script is actually executed or the old script still been executed unless you check the script deployment.

If there is a way to detect the script filename and add it in the suite script to display the script filename in the **console** while operating the record? (Then the developer and tester can know which scripts are executed in the record.)

PS: I am using API version 2, and the script types mostly are Client Script and User Event Script.

Comment: You'd probably get better results using some Netsuite terms.

Comment: Excuse me, what are the NetSuite terms?

Comment: Things like script type: suitlet, restart etc. ;Execution context; suitescript version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only client scripts have access to the console.
Often while working on client scripts I'll add a console.log statement that I change whenever it appears that I am getting cached content.

Generally though on Chrome and Firefox just doing a shift-refresh ensures I have the most recently uploaded client script. The appearance of a "stuck" cache is usually operator error (mine)

Server side scripts do not cache so whenever you start a script after you've uploaded the script's file then that's what is running.

There is no API to get the currently executing file(s).